# Push notifications not received when sent over FCM but do when sent over APN on IOS

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problems sending push notifications to a cordova app in IOS devices through FCM, on android it works fine. I use phonegap-plugin-push to handle them.

When notifications are sent from the server or FCM console they don't arrive and no error arises. When I manually send notifications using Pusher, with the APN token that I get from the plugin output they arrive correctly.

The APN certificates put into FCM are correct because the APN token obtained in the plugin is correct. So it seems to be a problem with the FCM-APN integration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wonders, it was a problem with the plugin. Fix it by replacing it with cordova-plugin-firebase